# Read all buffer data from serial port with C#

Tags: c#, serial-port, port, serial-communication

I have some problems using System.IO.Ports in C# to read data from a serial port. The only method thar works is the "Read" method, but it only read "defined" number of characters and i need to read all available data like "Tera Term" or "Hercules" do. Here is my DLL method that reads the buffer:

```
public String ReadMessage(String port, int timeout, int dataSize)
{
    String res;

    try
    {
        _serial_port = new SerialPort();
        _serial_port.PortName = port;
        _serial_port.BaudRate = 19200;
        _serial_port.Parity = Parity.None;
        _serial_port.DataBits = 8;
        _serial_port.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        _serial_port.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        _serial_port.ReadTimeout = timeout;
        _serial_port.DtrEnable = true;
        _serial_port.RtsEnable = true;

        _serial_port.Open();
        _serial_port.DiscardInBuffer();

        int totalBytes = _serial_port.BytesToRead;

        if (totalBytes > 0)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[totalBytes];
            _serial_port.Read(buffer, 0, totalBytes);
            res = ByteArrayToString(buffer);                   
        }
        else
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[dataSize];

            for (int len = 0; len < buffer.Length;)
            {
                len += _serial_port.Read(buffer, len, buffer.Length - len);
            }

            res = ByteArrayToString(buffer);                    
        }

        _serial_port.Close();

        return res;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex is UnauthorizedAccessException || ex is TimeoutException)
        {
            _serial_port.Close();
        }

        return ex.ToString();
    }
}
```

I know there are other methods to read data like: "ReadByte", "ReadChar", "ReadExisting", "ReadLine" and "ReadTo" but none of them are working, am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Well, you open port, discard anything is in input buffer and then expect it to contain valid data? 
Why do you get "all the data in buffer" when probably there is any and get whole buffer when there is no data?

Comment: Thanks, i use the  _serial_port.DiscardInBuffer() method to clean the previous "read" data in buffer.

Comment: So what do you consider end of transmission? Do you send some end character / character sequence? Maybe some period of "silence"? Maybe you should consider attaching length in the beginning of the transmission?

Comment: Reading the buffer automatically clears it. Discarding it again may loose data that is received in the mean time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the problem here is that for example in programs like Tera Term or Hercules it is not necessary to specify when the string is finished transmitting or the size of the string, I think it sends a character at the end of each transmission to warn To the receiver that the total of the message was sent. I believe that the sender sends some character / value to indicate that the message has been transmitted, but I do not know what it is.

Comment: @imqqmi thanks, i wont use it, but stil dont work unless i specify the data size

Comment: Neither do we, it completely depends on the sender. Just capture some sample data, save it to a file and open the file in a hex editor. If it's ascii, use an ascii lookup table to find out what newline characters there are and split the data into strings.

Comment: As said the data size is whats received at that moment in the buffer. Don't think in whole file parts, think in packets that make up the file.

Comment: @imqqmi That also seemed a good idea at first, however, the data that I must read always vary and since I could not "work" other methods that are not specifying the number of characters, I could not read that final value that indicates the "end of transmision", I imagine it must be a universal value since both Tera Term and Hercules read up there.

Comment: Terminal software do exactly the same, they constantly poll a buffer, and if there's anything there it will print the text, then if a newline is found it will print the next bit of text on a new line. It has no idea what is the beginning or the end of the stream. That's by design how the serial port works. It's like a river that continuously flows water. A bucket a time you get the water out until you fill a larger tank. Once done you look inside the tank to see what you got :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The serial port is a stream device, it can continuously receive data. You'll need to set a timer as long the serial port is open to continuously check if there's anything in the buffer and copy it to a buffer or file on disk as soon as possible to prevent a buffer overflow.

You need to check the data contents to find out what is received and when all of it is received. This depends on the sender. You can't just say receive all there is to receive, it's a continous stream as far as the serial port is concerned. The actual data needs to specify the protocol, start and stop conditions.

**EDIT**

Here's a code snippet I use to capture floppy disk data through a usb to rs232 device at 5mbit/sec:

```
    // Capture handler
    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Read data from serial port, poll every 10ms
        // If data is there, read a block and write it to array
        int bytestoread = 0;
        //byte buf;

        timer2.Stop();
        try
        {
            bytestoread = serialPort1.BytesToRead;
        }

        catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
        {
            tbr.Append("Serial connection lost. Exception type:" + ex.ToString());
            if ((uint)ex.HResult == 0x80131509)
            {
                timer2.Stop();
            }
        }

        if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
        {
            if (bytestoread != 0)
            {
                bytespersecond += bytestoread;

                byte[] temp = new byte[bytestoread];

                if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
                    serialPort1.Read(temp, 0, bytestoread);

                tempbuffer.Add(temp);
                processing.indexrxbuf += bytestoread;
                recentreadbuflength += bytestoread;

                //update the scatterplot, this may have a performance hit
                processing.rxbuf = tempbuffer.SelectMany(a => a).ToArray();
                rxbuf = processing.rxbuf;
                if (Setrxbufcontrol == null) return;
                Setrxbufcontrol();

            }
            timer2.Start();
        }
    }
```

setup code for serial port. I defined large buffers to prevent overflows:

```
        serialPort1.BaudRate = 5000000;
        serialPort1.NewLine = "\r\n";
        serialPort1.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 500000;
        serialPort1.ReadBufferSize = 1048576;
```

**EDIT 2**

Steps to read from a serial port:

1. Define a received data array to hold the data
2. Open serial port
3. Set a timer to read data continuously until user hits disconnect button
4. timer tick method checks the length of data in serial buffer, then read that length into the receive buffer defined in step 1. Keep track of total received data by adding the serial buffer length to a static variable.
5. In another timer you could check the received data array for new lines. Copy all data to an array of strings, or to a textbox. Or just copy the data as a string to the textbox to see what's in it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the problem here is that for example in programs like Tera Term or Hercules it is not necessary to specify when the string is finished transmitting or the size of the string, I think it sends a character at the end of each transmission to warn To the receiver that the total of the message was sent.

Comment: See updated code. Please tell us what exactly isn't working in the form of: what you get, what you expected.

Comment: Added steps to setup and use serial port.

Comment: The problem here is that i am reading data from a sender but some times it has 120 characters and some times it has 122. If i specify the buffer to read 120 and the sender send 122 it looses two characters. If i specify the buffer to read 122 and it send 120 the program crashess since it cant read 122 characters. Thats why y need to made the read method dinamic.

Comment: No you don't get how it works. Windows or whatever operating system has a serial buffer that will make sure, up to a certain point, that data doesn't get lost. At 19200 baud this is trivial for all current PCs, arduinos, PICs etc. Your C# application allows you to see how much data is received in that serial buffer. This amount you can copy to your own array for processing. Since it takes some time to receive data, you need to read it at different intervals of say 100 milliseconds. The first time you check the buffer it may contain 80 bytes, the next 20 bytes etc.

Comment: The operating system will never know for sure when data is finsished receiving as it cannot know. It's not in the nature of the serial port to know. It is just available to receive whatever bytes there may be. It's at the point you've got it into your own array that you can start analyzing what's received and how to interpret the data. There's no absolute lengths. Just packets of data.

Comment: To wrap it up, the answer what you are doing wrong is open the serial port, check the buffer immediately (which at 2GHz processor could be a few nano seconds) see that it hasn't received something yet which is very likely at 19200 baud, then try to read a fixed amount which also fails (this isn't supposed to work like that). You need to allow the serial buffer time to read data before checking if something is in the buffer at all. Using a timer solves that problem, then read the amount of bytes that's in the buffer. Try adding Thread.Sleep(5000) right after serial.open().